# Using display:none still produce blank space

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

I'm actually making an app with Cordova for a school project. I use jQuery to hide and show parts of the code, consisting of questions and answers. The problem is that when jQuery hides and shows questions there's blank space between the top of the screen and the displayed text.

Here's what the app shows when all the questions are answered (in French):[image: Application with display:none not working as expected]

I tried with `$('#numero').hide();`/`$('#numero').show();` and `$('#numero').css({"display":"none"});`/`$('#numero').css({"display":"inline"})` and the blank space is still visible.

Here's my actual js code:

```
var bluedata = [];
var numu = 0;
var numd = 0;
var hour = 0;

function sendData() {
  console.log("Sending...");
  bluetoothSerial.write(bluedata);
}

document.getElementById('btn-add').onclick = function() {
  $('#numeroplus').css({"display":"inline"});
  $('#numero1').css({"display":"inline"});
  $('#numero2').css({"display":"inline"});
  $('#btn-add').css({"display":"none"});
};
document.getElementById('btn-suivant').onclick = function() {
  numu = document.getElementById('numero').value;
  numd = document.getElementById('numeroplus').value;
  $('#numeroplus').css({"display":"none"});
  $('#numero').css({"display":"none"});
  $('#numero1').css({"display":"none"});
  $('#numero2').css({"display":"none"});
  $('#numerotel').css({"display":"none"});
  $('#frequencesms').css({"display":"inline"});
  $('#freqhour').css({"display":"inline"});
  $('#btn-add').css({"display":"none"});
  $('#btn-suivant').css({"display":"none"});
  $('#btn-suivant1').css({"display":"inline"});
  bluedata.push(numu);

  if (numd.length !== 0) {
    bluedata.push(numd);
  }
};
document.getElementById('btn-suivant1').onclick = function() {
  $('#frequencesms').hide();
  $('#freqhour').hide();
  hour = document.getElementById('freqhour').value;
  bluedata.push(hour);
  console.log(bluedata);
  $('#btn-suivant1').hide();
  $('#afterconf').show();
  sendData();
};
```

And here's my HTML code (I use Materialize to make an Android-like app):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bower_components/materialize/dist/css/materialize.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="css/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="css/bower_components/materialize/dist/js/materialize.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <title>La Piscine de la SIN</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a class="brand-logo center">La Piscine</a>
  </div>
</nav>
 <div class="container">
<form class="col s12">
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field">
  <input placeholder="Premier numéro" id="numero" type="tel" pattern="^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}$"><br/>
  <br/>
  <input placeholder="Deuxième numéro" id="numeroplus" style="display: none" type="tel" pattern="^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}$"><br/>
  <br/><a id="btn-add">Ajouter un numéro de téléphone supplémentaire</a><br/>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  <br/><button type="button" id="btn-suivant" class="btn btn-suivant btn-lg btn-primary">Suivant</button>
  </div><div class="container">
<form class="col s12">
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field">
    <p id="frequencesms" style="display: none; text-align: center">À quelle heure voulez-vous recevoir un SMS sur l'état actuel de la piscine ?</p>
    <input id="freqhour" style="display: none" type="time"><br/>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <br/><button type="button" id="btn-suivant1" style="display: none" class="btn btn-suivant btn-lg btn-primary">Suivant</button>
  </div><div id="afterconf" style="display:none">
    <h5>Félicitations, votre système d'alertes est maintenant configuré !</h5>
    <p>Vous communiquerez désormais avec le système en envoyant un SMS au numéro qui vient de vous contacter.</p>

    <h5>Liste des commandes pouvant être envoyées :</h5>
      <p>HELP<br/>TEMPERATURE<br/>EAU<br/>CHLORE</p>
  </div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mrtino.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/o6sx8nuc/

Comment: try visibility hidden

Comment: Are you sure, its the same element taking the blank space? A fiddle or snippet would be much more accurate to help you on your issue..

Comment: Create a fiddle please!

Comment: try thesie: 
1. Make  sure there is no margin on the element above which the gap is forming.
2. Try changing the height and width = 0 instead of hiding(not a good practice, just to confirm)

Comment: @new_user I just checked and there's no margin on my elements. I tried with height and width = 0 and the result is worse https://lut.im/QeL22GDT7l/CCGObObk6HZyJQgd.jpg

Comment: Exactly after `<nav></nav>` there is a form like this `<div class="container">
<form class="col s12">` , add a css `display:none` to this form after displaying content. that will remove the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i've sorted out your problem!

The blank space in your app was caused by empty divs with the class "container". I added my solution on line 37 (inside the JavaScript section) in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpeexen1/4/)

The code i added was:

```
$('.container').hide();
```